# Memory leak when manually compiling directives in Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, memory-leaks, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to manually compile a directive and add it to the DOM via JQuery. The directive is a simple div with an ngClick handler. No JQuery plugins are used in the directive itself (which seems to be the focus of many of the other memory leak threads).

If you run a profiler you will find that it leaks nodes. Is there something that can be done to fix this or is it a problem in JQuery/Angular?

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wsgKL/1/)
[Profiler screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/8rx18ln7n/)

HTML

```
<div ng-app="TestApp">
    <buttons></buttons>
    <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var ButtonsCtrl = function($scope, $compile) {
    this.scope = $scope;
    this.compile = $compile;
};

ButtonsCtrl.prototype.toggle = function() {
    var c = angular.element('#container').children();

    if (0 in c && c[0]) {
        c.scope().$destroy();
        c.remove();
    } else {
        var s = this.scope.$new();
        this.compile('<thing color="blue"></thing>')(s).appendTo('#container');
    }
};

var ThingCtrl = function($scope) {};
ThingCtrl.prototype.clicky = function() {
    alert('test');
};

var module = angular.module('components', []);
module.directive('buttons', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<button ng-click="ctrl.toggle()">toggle</button>',
        controller: ButtonsCtrl,
        controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    }
});

module.directive('thing', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            color: '@'
        },
        template: '<div style="width:50px;height:50px;background:{{color}};" ng-click="ctrl.clicky()"></div>',
        controller: ThingCtrl,
        controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    };
});

angular.module('TestApp', ['components']);
```

Comment: What exactly is the error/leak? Please edit question and put those details in. :-)

Comment: I already mentioned that it leaks nodes. I updated the fiddle link which was initially incorrect.

[Click here for profiler screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/8rx18ln7n/)

Answer (score 0):

If you cache the template function that $compile returns, then call that with a new scope, the memory leak seems to decrease to only one node per click.

```
var ButtonsCtrl = function($scope, $compile) {
    this.scope = $scope;
    this.makeThing = $compile('<thing color="blue"></thing>');
    this.thingScope = null;
};
```

Additionally, removing the jQuery wrappers from the ButtonsCtrl.toggle() method appears to eliminate the node leak altogether.

```
ButtonsCtrl.prototype.toggle = function() {
    var container = document.getElementById('container');

    if (this.thingScope) {
        container.removeChild(container.childNodes[0]);
        this.thingScope.$destroy();
        this.thingScope = null;
    } else {
        this.thingScope = this.scope.$new();
        container.appendChild(this.makeThing(this.thingScope)[0]);
    }
};
```

[See what you think.](http://jsfiddle.net/restjohn/aAq7d/)

Comment: best to destroy the child scope before you remove it from the DOM